# Can't get column names after first table return from Stored procedure in pymssql

Tags: python, pymssql

I have a procedure in sql server that returns multiple tables:

```
create procedure newtest
as 
begin
   select 1 as a
   select 2 as b
end
```

In python, cursor.description just returns first column name: a

I want to get every column name in each table.

How can I do that?

This is my code:

```
cur.execute(com)
                num_tables=0
                while True:
                    print(cur.description)
                    ret=cur.fetchall()   

                    if len(ret)>0: 
                        ret_list.append(ret)
                        num_tables+=1
                        print(ret)                       
                    else:
                        break
```

Comment: Still no answer?

Answer (score 3):

If the command returns multiple tables (i.e. multiple result sets). You can use [Cursor.nextset()](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0249/#nextset) to switch from one set to the next one.

Something like :

```
num_tables = 0
while True:
    print(cur.description)

    # all lines of the current set
    ret = cur.fetchall()

    if len(ret) > 0:
        ret_list.append(ret)
        num_tables += 1
        print(ret)

    # check and fetch the next set
    if not cur.nextset():
        break
```

The result sets are not forced to have the same column count. For example with :

```
create procedure newtest
as 
begin
   select 1 as a
   select 2 as b, 3 as c
end
```

The result is :

```
(('a', <class 'int'>, None, 10, 10, 0, False),)
[(1, )]
(('b', <class 'int'>, None, 10, 10, 0, False), ('c', <class 'int'>, None, 10, 10, 0, False))
[(2, 3)]
```

Comment: I've used cur.connection._conn.get_header() for every table returns, and it worked

Comment: If possible I would recommend using standard (PEP 249) functions instead of driver specific or undocumented ones